# Connection Pool vs Connection as parameter

Tags: java, database, performance, jdbc, database-connection

My program is using connection as parameter.

For example, I define connection parameter in my main class then I pass the connection as parameter when I call method from another class. would it make any difference to the program performance if i replace with connection pool?

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely do not worry about *performance* on such a "naive" level. You only focus on performance when you see performance issues (note: of course, you avoid to do outright stupid things). And when you see real performance problems, you do **profiling** in order to understand the *real* problems.

In other words: you should focus on creating a good [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) OO design instead. And (as far as that is possible without seeing any code of yours) from that point of view, you definitely stick with passing in a Connection.

You see, you have some "client" code that is supposed to do "something" with that connection. So the **responsibility** of that client is exactly that: to use that connection to manipulate whatever that Connection connects to. It should **not** be the responsibility to also "establish" that connection.

Meaning: one piece of client code is responsible for fetching a Connection from the Connection Pool; and some other client code is responsible for using that Connection to do whatever. You should not mix those two aspects. Otherwise you reduce your options to *re-use* the individual functionalities; and you couple elements, that simple do not need to be coupled.

Comment: Passing a Connection around is generally not a very good OO design, because this is the kind of detail (the fact that retrieval is implemented using a JDBC-connected database) that you shouldn't be exposing in an API. If you need to work with raw JDBC Connections, then it's probably best to use something like Spring JDBC template to hide away the dirty plumbing details of obtaining and managing the connection, rather then passing the Connection object around. (Spring will use a ThreadLocal to store the Connection if a transaction is active)

Comment: thanks i will look into spring jdbc template @ErwinBolwidt